# Firestore: Listen for document changes and store realtime data in Provider using Flutter

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, database-design, flutter-provider, state-management

**Current Situation**

In my App I use Provider for state management and Cloud Firestore as database.

Until now I used simple `get` querys to fetch data from Firestore like below:

```
class Database {
  final usersCol = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');
  final myUser = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!;

  Future<List<Workout>> getWorkouts() async {
    var a = await usersCol
        .doc(myUser.uid)
        .collection('workouts')
        .orderBy('date', descending: true)
        .limit(30)
        .get();
    return a.docs.map((doc) => Workout.fromFirestore(doc.data())).toList();
  }
}
```

When opening the app I fetch data from Firestore and store it in Provider:

```
class WorkoutsProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  List<Workout> _workouts = [];
  List<Workout> get workouts => [..._workouts];

  // called in main() when app gets initialized
  Future getData() async {
    _workouts = await Database().getWorkouts();
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

**Goal Situation**

To get realtime data from Firestore I now want to use a `Stream`:

```
class Database {
  final usersCol = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');
  final myUser = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!;

  Stream<List<Workout>> getWorkoutsStream() {
    return usersCol
        .doc(myUser.uid)
        .collection('workouts')
        .orderBy('date', descending: true)
        .limit(30)
        .snapshots()
        .map((list) {
      return list.docs.map((doc) => Workout.fromFirestore(doc.data())).toList();
    });
  }
}
```

In my Provider I create a listener to ensure having always latest data stored in provider in `_workouts`. With that I am able to show always updated data from `_workouts` in UI and do some business logic on `_workouts` as well.

```
class WorkoutsProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  List<Workout> _workouts = [];
  List<Workout> get workouts => [..._workouts];

  // called in main() when app gets initialized
  Future getData() async {
    // before:
    // _workouts = await Database().getWorkouts();

    // now:
    Database().getWorkoutsStream().listen((workouts) {
      _workouts = workouts;
      notifyListeners();
    });
  }
}
```

**My Question**

Is this a good approach to deal with realtime data or could this lead to unwanted bugs or anything by having a listener in Provider instead of having a `StreamBuilder` in every Widget?

Note: The workouts Stream I listen to is not updated often and is normally only updated by the user himself and not from "outside"

Comment: why not using this one: https://pub.dev/documentation/provider/latest/provider/StreamProvider-class.html?

Comment: My WorkoutsProvider is more complex than what is shown in the question with more business logic on _workouts which is not possible with StreamProvider I think. Therefore I want to keep this Provider with the _workouts field.

Comment: everything you do inside `listen`'s callback you can do with `Stream` api, for more see: https://dart.dev/tutorials/language/streams#working-with-streams